# Netsuite, how to search for Open Vendor Bills (Transactions)

Tags: java, netsuite, suitetalk

Would seem to be simple but as so often with netsuite, it's painful. This is what i have so far:

```
        TransactionSearch invoiceSearch = new TransactionSearch();        

        TransactionSearchBasic invoiceSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        SearchEnumMultiSelectField criteria = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();                       

        criteria.setOperator(SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.ANY_OF);
        String[] statuses = new String[] { TransactionStatus.BILL_OPEN.toString() };

        stats.getSearchValue().addAll(Arrays.asList(statuses));

        invoiceSearchBasic.setStatus(stats);
```

If i comment out the invoiceSearchBasic.setStatus line I get all the transactions fine (including the ones i want with a staus of "Open") but when it's there I get nothing. Needless to say changing TransactionStatus.BILL_OPEN.toString() to "Open" doesn't work either, that would be far too easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've resolved it. For anyone else, this is the problem:

from the TransactionStatus enumeration:

```
@XmlEnumValue("_billOpen")
BILL_OPEN("_billOpen")
```

which when you log the toString value it gives **BILL_OPEN** (not **_billOpen**)

but it's **_billOpen** we need!

solution:

```
SearchEnumMultiSelectField criteria = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
criteria.setOperator(SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.ANY_OF);
String[] statuses = new String[] { "_billOpen" };
criteria.getSearchValue().addAll(Arrays.asList(statuses));
```